# Mutliple laravel apps on the same website

Tags: php, laravel-4

I currently have two Laravel v4.2 projects hosted on two separate websites. I want to host the two applications on the same website under a sub-directory. Such as `www.domain.com/lara_app1` and `www.domain.com/lara_app2`. I've done some searching already, but was unable to find anything that really helped.

However, I cannot seem to find anything specific enough to get this done. I currently have the two separate apps set up like so:

```
domain-one
- app
- bootstrap
- public_html
    - assets
        - *bootstrap v3 and other css/js*
    - index.php (from laravel)
    - .htaccess (from laravel)
- vendor

domain-two
- app
- bootstrap
- public_html
    - assets
        - *bootstrap v3 and other css/js*
    - index.php (from laravel)
    - .htaccess (from laravel)
- vendor
```

They're both connecting the same database, but as different users. How would I set it up as the following?

```
domain
- app1
      - *project files*
- app2
      - *project files*
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably solved via the web server. If you are using nginx you could adjust this nodejs example to your needs: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-host-multiple-node-js-applications-on-a-single-vps-with-nginx-forever-and-crontab)

Comment: @BastianHofmann Thanks, I didn't use this solution, but it did lead me to the solution I used.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue by creating a subdomain for each application on the site.